# What is the replacement of strcmp sscanf and sprintf in embedded system?

Tags: c, string, embedded

Working on embedded systems, came to know that `sprintf`,`sscanf`, and `strcmp` was not recmmended.

1. `sscanf`

   There are instance where i have to parse numbers and other important data from strings. Also the strings might contain different type of data.

   What is the suggested replacement for sscanf in embedded systems?
2. `sprintf`

   Similar to `sscanf` `sprintf` is also required.
3. `strcmp`,`strstr`

   strcmp and strstr is well required in project.

   Is memcpy preferred in embedded system to strcmp?

*What are the  main important points to be kept in mind while working on strings?*

```
char array[10]="data",copy[10];
for(int i=0;i<10 && array[i]!='\0';i++)
   copy[i]=array[i];
```

is this also an alternative for strcpy? How well is the sustainablity of the above code

Comment: Not really opinion based - if the printf or scanf is larger than available FLASH memory opinions do not matter :)

Comment: It depends of what kind of "embedded system" you're working on. There are tiny microcontrollers with just a few kB of Flash and maybe a few hundred bytes of RAM, but there are also embedded systems with several gigabytes of memory, where this would be a non-issue. So, which kind of embedded system are you talking about, specifically?

Comment: I'm using a 72kB Flash and 16kB RAM.

Comment: _"What are the main important points to be kept in mind while working on strings?"_: I'd say: beware of buffer overflows and make sure your strings are always NUL terminated.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: I don't agree with most the assumptions. The main goal using these functions, **in general**, is avoiding unexpected buffer overflows due to unexpected data format. If you have control on the strings to be parsed, there's no reason to avoid using `sscanf`, for example. The main problem, actually, with so lilmited flash/RAM availability is that you might want to write your own optimized version istead of trusting on library functions provided by the crosscompiler (or you don't have them at all).

Comment: "know that sprintf,sscanf, and strcmp was not recmmended." --> Please provide a link to that idea.  to well answer, one needs to know why they are not recommended.  Sometimes these limits are due to memory architecture (`const` vs. not `const`) in these C-like compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to write your own version of `strcpy`

So instead of this:

```
char array[10]="data",copy[10];
for(int i=0;i<10 && array[i]!='\0';i++)
   copy[i]=array[i];
```

You would have something this:

```
// This sticks to specification from the standard C library.
// For your needs you may want something slightly different
// for example controlling the maximum size of the destination buffer

char *strcpy(char *to, const char *from)
{
    char *dest = to;
    while (*to++ = *from++) ;

    return dest;
}
...
char array[10]="data",copy[10];
strcpy(copy, array);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked and `while(*to++ = *from++);`

Answer (score 2):

I do not know who told you that `strcmp` or `strstr` are "not recommended" but it is not the truth.

If you program very small uC with 16kB of FLASH using printf and scanf family of function is just too expensive (printf with no float and long support is 5-7kB). For this kind of micros - write your own functions or use tiny printf implementations - you have plenty available on the net. Instead of scanf just write simple parser suitable for your application.

Comment: Thanks, but is memcpy a replacement for strcpy? Is there any benefit while using memcpy?

Comment: @ATHMESHANDROID no, `memcpy` and `strcpy` are different functions that do different things. What's wrong with using `strcpy`? It's a tiny function that should be available on any platform. If it's not, then you can write your own `strcpy` (hint: it's 2 lines of code). Same for `strcmp` which is only slightly more complicated than `strcpy`.

Comment: maybe by adding a forloop to copy string elements will be useful.

Comment: @ATHMESHANDROID no, this is a terrible idea. Rewrite your own `strcpy` function. It's 2 lines of code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky strcpy is same bad as the calling code. Write good code and strcpy will 100% good and safe.

Comment: @P__J__ I didn't get your comment.

Comment: @Jabberwocky @P__J__ , 

>` char arr[10]="Data",copy[10];`

>`for(int i=0;i<10;i++)`

>`{`

>`copy[i]=arr[i];`

>`}`


Is this what you meant?

Comment: @ATHMESHANDROID your comment is ill formatted, and no I probably didn't mean that at all. But I think this conversation is becoming a quite different question. I suggest you write an all new question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I apologise, i couldnt provide a well format in the comment section, so i have edited the same question

Comment: @ATHMESHANDROID: What Jabberwocky is aiming at is that, while you may not have `strcpy` (or any other standard function) available from the *standard library*, it should be easy enough to write your **own** version of `strcpy` (because it's only two lines of code). And as soon as you copy strings in more than one or perhaps two places, having a *function* in *one* place will save memory space over having a loop everywhere you are copying strings. (Are you *sure* you're up to trying your hand at embedded programming? This is *really* basic...)